# can I throw this away without it affecting whatever it is that nvidia does on my computer

Tags: drivers

an install 3d driver just appeared one day on my pc. i don't want 3d glasses, don't use auto cad. can I throw this away without it affecting whatever it is that nvidia does on my computer (something that i am strugling to determine. I just don't want to bulk up on stuff i will never use.`

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you mean by an Nvidia 3d driver install just appeared on your computer was that Nvidia wants to updates its driver and a notification appeared in the Windows Notification Area saying that it had a 3d driver update available. Correct me if I miss interpreted anything. If however my understanding is correct than I would advise you not to deal with the hassle of updating to a 3d driver because updating a driver can result it complicated unexpected issues. Also as you stated you would not even be utilizing the 3d driver. Ask yourself this does it work well? If it does than don't change it. If it doesn't than make changes and tweak it.